# Reading a File character by character then putting them into a for loop pattern in java

Tags: java

I am currently working on a small for-loop pattern and I stumbled upon a road block in my project. Basically, what I want is to make a for loop pattern from my .java file that reads the source char by char and replace the asterisks in my current for-loop pattern:

[image]

Into something like this

[image]

Here's the current code that I have that does the for-loop pattern

```
for( i = 1; i <= 5; ++i, z = 0) { // first line
    for(int space = 1; space <= segments - i; ++space) {
        System.out.print("  ");
    }

    while(z != 2 * i - 1) {
        System.out.print("* ");
       z++;
    }

    System.out.println();
}   
for( i = 1; i <= 10; ++i, z = 0) { // second line
    for(int space = 1; space <= segments - i; ++space) {
        System.out.print("  ");
    }

    while(z != 2 * i - 1) {
        System.out.print("* ");
       z++;
    }

    System.out.println();
}
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Where are you stuck? Can you read in a file?

Comment: Yes, but the problem is that it prints everything from the java file instead of printing it char by char just like the asterisks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is sample for how you can read a file char by char,

```
try {
    BufferedReader r=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt"));
    int ch;
    while((ch=r.read())!=-1){
        System.out.print((char)ch);
    }
} catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.print((char)ch);
}
```

To implement it in your code, just put this while loop in your while loop of asterisk's.